# Sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x+i)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I am trying to solve $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x+i)}$$

I have no idea what approach should I be used to solve? I hope somebody out there can guide me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\large\textbf{Hint} :$

Let $ n\geq 2 $, we have the following : \begin{aligned}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{k!}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{k}{\left(x+i\right)}}}&=\frac{1}{x-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\left(\frac{k!}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}{\left(x+i\right)}}-\frac{\left(k+1\right)!}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{k}{\left(x+i\right)}}\right)}\\ &=\frac{1}{x-1}\left(1-\frac{n!}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}{\left(x+i\right)}}\right)\end{aligned}

Comment: Very nice indeed!